# ROV tether: will DC power supply interfere with the control signal?

Tags: power-supply, noise, rs485

I'm designing a tethered underwater drone. I think I will use RS-485 for control.

I can either place batteries in the ROV itself or supply it with electricity via tether. In the latter case, will DC supply line create noise in the control wires? The ROV impedance is going to vary, as far as I understand this is going to cause short voltage drops in the supply line even if it's connected to a battery, isn't it?

Comment: Did you look at OpenROV ? https://www.openrov.com/ They probably have solved most of your problems already.

Comment: What are the voltage/current requirements of the ROV?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of wires you are using, my personal experience is that UTP ethernet is fine, twisted pair helps to reduce EMI and therefore noise in control wires.

Comment: Wire sizing depends on the wattage needed at the load along with the voltage. From that you can determine the current and check if the wire is capable of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand several things in your question. What is "ROV impedance" and why would it vary? Are you referring to different tether length? Also you didn't specify key parameter: maximum depth. One thing is toy submarine in a pool (for which even USB cable will do), another is open water drone.

Putting those aside and looking at title question, the answer is: *Properly designed* DC power supply should not interfere with *properly wired* control signal.

Battery is ideal low-noise source, but DC-DC with good filtering can be used as well. This would take care on the control side. On the drone side loop power lines through ferrite core or ring right before they enter cable. Also add 0.1 uF ceramic capacitors between the motor contacts and between contacts and motor case (total 3 caps per motor).

The control wiring should be twisted pair with additional ground (shielded cable can be used with shield acting as ground). Considering operating conditions you might want to look for marine or plenum rated automation cable, something like [Belden](https://www.belden.com/products/industrial/cable/bus-cable/rs485) makes.

If you don't want to have separate power and control cables one option is to find suitable cable with 4 twisted pairs, use one pair for two control lines, one pair as positive power wire and one pair as negative power/ground. This would leave you with remaining twisted pair that can be used either as separate ground (instead of negative line) or for additional control/telemetry.

Alternative wiring option is to take 1 wire from one twisted pair and connect it in parallel with one wire from another pair, making one power line. The remaining wires from each pair will make second power line.

Note that I still recommend using separate cables for control and power. Not so much for interference prevention as for better fit of the gauge for the task. You can find nice thick but flexible silicone wire for power and thin shielded cable with single twisted pair (similar to USB cable) for control.

In the end, the choice between on-board and remote power depends on the distance and reliability requirements. Too long cable will be either too thick or waste huge part of the available power, plus if tether is cut and your drone does not have backup battery or emergency surfacing measures it is basically lost. On the other hand on-board battery limits the operating time.

Comment: There are ICs (including MCU) and motors, I guess their power consumption isn't constant. As for the tether length, it's going to be 20 to 30 meters at most.

Comment: Variable power consumption and variable impedance are quite different things. With 30m you probably can get away with good quality Cat5e/Cat6 cable (about 10~20 Ohm/100m) although it is not the best choice. Use full pair + 1 line of  third pair for each power line (3 wires in parallel) and remaining pair for RS-485. Or look for more flexible cable with multi-stranded wires rated to your power requirements. In any case, if you use twisted pair + ground for control and good DC source there should not be any interference. I'll also add a note on filtering to the answer.